# Google chrome extension similar to notepad++

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, syntax-highlighting

Does anyone here knows a google chrome extension that automatically highlights certain js, css, and html codes? Like a syntax highlighter that works on blog's HTML editor.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to actually have a proper syntax-highlighter (server-side or client-side) that will properly highlight code for *all* browsers?

Comment: Yes, but I work on multiple blogging platforms (Blogger, Wordpress, and custom) and I don't have access to the server. I need it to make the work easier for me when styling tables, paginated articles etc.

Comment: Then how about a client-side solution (like [highlight.js](https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js), there are many others) which is still browser neutral?

Answer (score 1):

I found [Syntaxic!](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/syntaxtic/cgjalgdhmbpaacnnejmodfinclbdgaci?hl=en) by searching Google for [chrome extension syntax highlighting]. I haven't tried it, but the ratings are good.

Answer (score 0):

[Caret](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/caret/fljalecfjciodhpcledpamjachpmelml?hl=en) could be used if you don't mind copy-paste between the editors,
on different pages.